# Plotting in R using plot function

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot few graphs using loops. I am now describing in details.

First I have a function which is calculates the y-variable (called `effect` for vertical axis)

```
effect<- function (x, y){
  exp(-0.35*log(x)
      +0.17*log(y)
      -0.36*sqrt(log(x)*log(y)/100))
}
```

Now I run the following code and use the option par to plot the lines in the same graph. I use `axis=FALSE` and `xlab=""` to get a plot without labels. I do this so that my labels are not re-written each time the loop runs and looks ugly.

```
for (levels in seq(exp(8), exp(10), length.out = 5)){
  x = seq(exp(1),exp(10), length.out = 20)
  prc= effect(levels,x)
  plot(x, prc,xlim = c(0,max(x)*1.05), ylim=c(0.0,0.3),
       type="o", xlab = "",ylab = "",  pch = 16, 
       col = "dark blue", lwd = 2, cex = 1, axes = F)
  label = as.integer(levels) #x variable
  text(max(x)*1.03,max(prc), label )
  par(new=TRUE)
}
```

Finally, I duplicate the plot command this time using the `xlab` and `ylab` options

```
plot(x, prc, xlab = "X-label", ylab = "effect", 
     xlim = c(0,max(x)*1.05), ylim = c(0,0.3), 
     type="l", col ='blue')
```

I have several other plots in the similar lines, using complex equations. I have two questions:

1. Is there an better option to have the same plot with smoother lines?
2. Is there an easier option with few lines to achieve the same, where I can place the texts (levels) for each line on the right with white background at the back?

[image: Output of the above program]

Comment: It's bad form to name a variable when a function/method already exists with that name. In your for loop, you use "levels" for the iterator. There is already a function `levels()` in base R. What are you asking for in your second question? Do you want the labels, "levels", to be in an axis on the right side? From what I can tell, they already have a white background and your `text()` doesn't seem to set a background parameter, so are you asking about position or is there a color difference I don't see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe working with the plot function was tedious and time consuming. So, I have finally used ggplot2 to plot. There were several help available online, which I have used.